# Is '-c' just shortened alias for '-codec' in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, command-line-arguments

I looked at the documentation and it does not seem clear to me. For example are the following two commands essentially the same?

```
ffmpeg -i .\video.mp4  -i .\metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 -codec: copy -y out.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i .\video.mp4  -i .\metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 -c copy out.mp4
```

If they are not the same, then what is the difference?

I am finding myself tripping over these two flags a lot and would like to know conclusively.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same as can be seen [in the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options):

> -c[*:stream_specifier*] *codec (input/output,per-stream)* 
> -codec[*:stream_specifier*] *codec (input/output,per-stream)*
>
> Select an encoder (when used before an output file) or a decoder (when used before an input file) for one or more streams. *codec* is the name of a decoder/encoder or a special value `copy` (output only) to indicate that the stream is not to be re-encoded.